# Can I get a pointer to the current function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, logging

Is it possible to get a pointer to the current function? If it is, how can I do so?

Motivation: I have a function doing some logging, and would like to call

```
log(currentfunc, "blabla")
```

Which does some output for example.

Comment: you can get the function's name with a macro if you want for logging purposes in most compilers. _____func_____ is the macro if memory serves

Comment: See also here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154852/get-a-pointer-to-the-current-function-in-c-gcc

Comment: Don't call your function `log` -- There's a commonly used function called `log` in math.h that returns the natural logarithm.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048670/pointer-to-current-function and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154852/get-a-pointer-to-the-current-function-in-c-gcc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a pointer to the current function in C (gcc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154852/get-a-pointer-to-the-current-function-in-c-gcc)

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the name of the current function (but not a pointer to it) via the predefined identifier `__func__` which is part of C99.

```
log(__func__, "blabla");
```

[Here's the reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r9.cbclx01/predefined_identifiers.htm)

Comment: Do you know a way to do it in c89? There's no need to do it in c89, but I would like to know it.

Comment: @cmusicmatze: No, in c89 the best you can do is use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` or make use of non-standard possibilities your implementation offers, if any.

Comment: @einpoklum: Not exactly. C++11 has `__FUNCTION__` which does the same. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126387/func-c11-functions-local-predefined-variable-wont-compile

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: IIANM, `__FUNCTION__` expands to a string, not an identifier.

Comment: @einpoklum: so does `__func__` in C99, doesn't it? You can't get a *pointer* to current function in either C or C++

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the pointer to a function, but the predefined identifier `__func__` returns the name of the function. Maybe that can help...

In fact, I'd replace your function `log` with a macro so you don't have to paste in the name every time, as such:

```
#define log(x) log(__func__,x)
```

Comment: @Kirilenko hmmm predefined identifier... okay

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of **__*FILE*__** and **__*LINE*__**. It will be work with [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) compilers.