# Is there any way to get the return type of the "current function"

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

I would like to write a template that would get as a parameter the return type of the function in which it is being instantiated.

For example, assume I've a `Result` templated class:

```
template<type T>
class Result {
    T _result_value;
    T& operator=( T that );
    ~Result( );
}
```

There would be several specializations for this class. In the destructor I would like to log the return type, and within the `operator=` assignment I would like to check and assert for error values.

Ideally, I would like to be able to have such a define:

```
#define RESULT Result< /* decltype magic for type of current function */ >
```

so I could use it:

```
HFILE MyOpenFile( ... ) {
    RESULT result;
}
```

...which will be deduced to `Result<HFILE>`. This is a simplified example: writing `RESULT` instead of `Result<HFILE>` isn't a big deal, but there are other scenarios where the return type of the current function isn't easily obtained.

Comment: can you use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype ?

Comment: I guess you'll at least have to pass the function name to the macro (e.g. `RESULT(MyOpenFile)`), and in the case of overloading, you'd still encounter ambiguities. Even [getting a pointer to the current function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2154852/1468366) is tricky, and getting a correctly typed pointer seems impossible without naming the function again.

Comment: @MvG, you can get around the overload ambiguity by passing to `decltype` the function + params, e.g. `decltype(foo(b))`, `decltype(foo(a, b))` will resolve correctly. However, it's a pain..

Comment: If it did exist, there would have to be limits on what a user could do with the information. Recursive use of such information could render a function's return type undecidable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There's nothing in C++ which refers to the "current function". The closest is `__func__` but that's a string literal. Hence, there's nothing to pass to `decltype`.

Not that you need it, with `auto`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible from inside a function because there is no dedicated object in memory representing it which can be referenced to deduce the type. It's possible for classes, via `decltype(*this)`.

Answer (score 4):

The most portable way I can think of is using `decltype`:

```
#define RESULT(func, ...) Result<decltype(func(__VA_ARGS__))>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    RESULT(main, argc, argv) result; // same as `Result<int> result;`
}
```

But this forces you to pass the function name and every argument it takes to the `RESULT` macro. I don't think this is avoidable, because there is no portable (and often not even a compiler-specific) way to get an identifier to the current function and/or arguments passed. Arguments passed matter thanks to overload ambiguities.

Here is a SSCCE: http://ideone.com/cPTjjF

Comment: you don't need the varargs business, simply define `RESULT` as `RESULT(f) Result<decltype(f)>` and then use as `RESULT(main(argc, argv))`...