# C++ decltype deducing current function returned type

Tags: c++, c++11, types, decltype, type-deduction

I would like to automatically deduce the returned type of the function I'm writing.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> test(){
    decltype(this_function) ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(9);
    return ret;
}
```

So far the best I've achieved is

```
std::vector<int> test(){
    decltype(test()) ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(9);
    return ret;
}
```

Which works but:

1. If I change function name I must change

   `decltype(test())`

   into

   `decltype(name())`
2. If I change function parameters I must change as well

   `decltype(test())`

   into

   `decltype(test(param1, param2))`

Is there a more elegant way of doing the same?

Comment: The changing-parameters problem can be solved, though not the function-renaming.

Comment: Why not use a template function? if would be as easy as T test(){ T ret ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13286605/1147772

Comment: Can you post an actual example where this would be needed? Here the type can by omitted with `return {5,9};` and `auto` helps in most cases.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to cleanly do this, C++ is missing the feature. D has this as `typeof(return)`, for example.

Comment: FWIW, In C++14 you'll be able to do [the opposite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Function_return_type_deduction).

Comment: I sometimes wonder why people try this hard not to copy a few characters from the previous line... Do you think this would be more readable? Are you under the assumption that changing the return type in the declaration can be done without looking inside the definition?

Comment: @jrok: I would not advertise it too much, people might want to use it! [And I don't particularly like that idea :)]

Comment: @jrok I've seen that, but i like this approach more.. If only there was a clean way of doing that.. In this way you would still have the returned types in the headers... which is very important for readability IMHO..

Comment: Hopefully "type of enclosing function" and "type of enclosing class" are near the top of the list of desired features for the reflection SG.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I like C++14 `auto` as return-type only in template meta-programming when the actual return type involving `typename` and sometime even `template`, is more difficult to understand, but I try to restrict myself `auto` for internal functions only; public API are usually better.

Comment: @Nawaz: ... but you make your own function meta-programming unfriendly. The deduced return type of a template function cannot be used in an SFINAE context.

Comment: Time for a down vote for lazy programming

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I wonder what will happen to standard headers once C++ 14 is done. if the header says `std::vector<int> foobar()` and the spec says `auto foobar();` you'd have to declare your own function auto. because changing c++ compilers might get you different return types. so it's not just saving some characters but giving library writers more freedoms.

Comment: @Alex: Standard headers won't probably use the deduced type, that is a feature more oriented to user code. The standard is a, hopefully, precise specification of behavior, it does not go into details as of how it is implemented, but the interface **must** be well defined (except in a few key places, the least). Also note that the deduced return type also places restrictions on how the function is implemented (what things can be returned, how the type is inferred...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'd say that concepts (if they go into C++ 17) are the constraining things in std headers of the future whereas `auto` and `decltype` is convenience compared to `typedef` to define types in templates.

Comment: @Alex: No, those are somehow orthogonal. Concepts constrain the inputs to the function, not the return type. The standard still needs to mandate that `std::vector<T>::operator[](size_type)` returns `reference_type`. That will **not** be transformed into: `auto operator[](size_type) { ... return X; }`, the standard *defines* what the function returns and it does so without providing the implementation, which in turn means that it cannot use *deduced* return types. Additionally, there are limitations as of what can be done with deduced return types, and that will limit the implementations.

Comment: @Alex: As I mentioned before, the deduced return type cannot be used in SFINAE contexts, it will cause a hard error. If the standard requires that `std::vector<int>::operator[]` return `int&`, then user code is allowed to do: `std::is_arithmetic<std::remove_reference<decltype(myvector[0])>::type>::value` in an SFINAE context to provide a specialized implementation of some function for arithmetic types. If the implementation of `std::vector` was done in terms of deduced return types the previous expression would be a *hard* error, rather than a substitution error rejecting a valid program

Comment: @Alex: deduced return type is far from a golden hammer, it is not just that you cannot abuse it to drive screws, it does not even drive *all* nails!

Answer (score 8):

Name the return type?

```
template <typename T=std::vector<int>>
T test(){
    T ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(9);
    return ret;
}
```

Please don't make me constrain this with `enable_if`.

Comment: This is clearly not the same. It defines a family of functions, and while you could constrain it with `enable_if` (as you mentioned), it is not the same as a single function. For example, you cannot use this to declare/define a virtual function.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas but the virtual function could just call this "implementation" function.

Answer (score 4):

The question is paradox:

In this example

```
std::vector<int> test(){
    decltype(test()) ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(9);
    return ret;
}
```

the function has to assume the decltype is a container supporting push_back with a value type of int. There is no way to predict it. Just changing the return type (to double) will break it.

Answer (score 2):

How about :

```
typedef std::vector<int> my_return_type;

my_return_type test(){
    my_return_type ret;
    ret.push_back(5);
    ret.push_back(9);
    return ret;
}
```

I think you won't have anything better without macros :)

Comment: @n.m. With a template you either authorize multiple versions of your function with types that would not necessarly make sense, or you explicitly prohibit them which add some ugly code :)

Comment: @drax Pfft - call it a feature! Caller-specifiable return type. I really missed my calling in marketing.

Comment: @Casey i cannot win against this :D

Comment: @drax Sorry I don't get it. Are you saying that *any* function template is a problem? What's with, oh, half of the standard library, is it useless now because "you either authorize multiple versions of your function with types that would not necessarly make sense, or you explicitly prohibit them which add some ugly code"? The standards committee will be surprised to hear that.

Comment: @n.m. Well isn't this the whole reason behind "concepts" ? :) IMO In the STL it is largely worth it, in the case of the OP the only reason is to avoid the copy of one type name, doest it deserve to promote your simple function to a more powerfull templated version and potentialy change the way your users use your code ?

Comment: I'm not talking about promoting `test` to a template. I'm talking about the case when `test` is *already* a template.

Comment: @n.m. If test is already a template i agree with you, but that's just not the case in the OP's code :)

Answer (score 1):

This might look weird but I think it does what you want it to do.

```
std::vector<int> create() { 
  std::vector<int> x;
  return x; 
}

auto myfunc() -> decltype(create()) {
  auto X = create();
  return X;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pre-C++1y (and post-C++1y, too), you could use a lambda to do the return type deduction for you, as in:

```
namespace
{
    auto test = []
    {
        std::vector<int> ret;
        ret.push_back(5);
        ret.push_back(9);
        return ret;
    };
}
```

Comment: Problem with lambdas is that they don't play nice with ADL.