# How can we know the caller function's name?

Tags: c

In the C language, `__FUNCTION__` can be used to get the ***current*** function's name.
But if I define a function named a() and it is called in b(), like below:

```
b()
{
    a();
}
```

Now, in the source code, there are lots of functions like b() that call a(), e.g. c(), d(), e()...

Is it possible, within a(), to add some code to detect the name of the function that called a()?

**Further:**

1. Sorry for the misleading typo. I have corrected it.
2. I am trying to find out which function calls a() for debugging purposes. I
   don't know how you do when in the same situation?
3. And my code is under vxWorks, but I am not sure whether it is related to C99 or
   something else.

Comment: Not sure. But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154852/get-a-pointer-to-the-current-function-in-c-gcc) maybe helpful to you

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it for debugging purpose?

Comment: If this is only for debugging you can define a as a macro, that way using `__func__` will return b, as you want.

Comment: Which compiler has **FUNCTION** to return the name of the current function? The identifier that is foreseen in the C standard for that is `__func__` IIRC.

Comment: what you write is wrong. `__FUNC__` returns the current method name AFAIK. To get the caller, you'd have to look at the stacktrace

Comment: @Daij-Djanm, how can a question be wrong? In any case I checked and the C standard defines `__func__` for that purpose (section 6.4.2.2). So again my question, what compiler has this with the identifier `FUNCTION`? That would be completely wrong, since that is any identifier that is clearly reserved for use in applications (by a C programmer).

Comment: "In C language, we can use FUNCTION to get the caller function's name." - first statement of the question. and that is wrong ^^

Comment: 1. Do you need platform-specific solution or cross-platform solution?
2. Do you need compile-time or run-time information?
It will be good if you brifely describe, what you are doing.

Comment: @JensGustedt: GCC has `__FUNCTION__`, so it propably a typo by the OP.

Comment: Underscores are significant to markdown, hence the bold formatting. I've edited to fix that, which hopefully will reduce the confusion a bit, but I haven't fixed the issue of whether the questioner should have mentioned the C99 standard version or the older GCC version.

Comment: @JensGustedt "how can a question be wrong?" -- More silly games, eh? Daij-Dan wrote "what you write is wrong", which is clearly true. "That would be completely wrong" -- which is what Daij-Dan said, but stronger.

Comment: If it is for debugging puposes have you tried to set a breakpoint in `a`? The other option would be to use a profiler and generate call graph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find \_\_FUNCTION\_\_, \_\_LINE\_\_ and \_\_FILE\_\_ of parent function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135276/how-to-find-function-line-and-file-of-parent-function)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's nothing you can do only in a.

However, with a simple standard macro trick, you can achieve what you want, IIUC showing the name of the caller.

```
void a()
{
    /* Your code */
}

void a_special( char const * caller_name )
{
    printf( "a was called from %s", caller_name );
    a();
}

#define a() a_special(__func__)

void b()
{
    a();
}
```

Comment: I had to declare the caller_name variable as `const char* caller_name`, but it worked!

Comment: Precision: `__func__` is part of the C99 standard, [...] `__FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`, provided for backward compatibility with old versions of GCC. (source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I use your example with ellipsis in function declaration, please? `void a(int a, char *fmt, ...)`
How can I include it in the macro definition?

Comment: @mulg0r Have a look at `va_list` , `va_arg` and companions. however I doubt you can apply this trick to a function using ellipsis: it should be written with `va_list` instead, just like the `vprintf` function series :-(

Comment: @mulg0r Using [variadic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) you can achieve what you want (eg.`#define a(...) a_special (__func__, __VA_ARGS__)`, for a function `void a_special(char const * caller_name, ...){}`) They are around in C since C99 and in C++ since C++11.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it with a gcc builtin.

> [`void * __builtin_return_address(int level)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html)

The following way should print the immediate caller of a function a().

Example:

```c
a() {
    printf ("Caller name: %pS\n", __builtin_return_address(0));
}
```

Comment: This does print return address (still useful), but not function name.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Linux system, you can use the `backtrace()` function.

See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) for more details and a code example.

Comment: In late 2020 it's available on macOS too.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
void a(<all param declarations to a()>);

#ifdef DEBUG
#  define a(<all params to a()>) a_debug(<all params a()>, __FUNCTION__)
void a_debug(<all params to a()>, const char * calledby);
#endif

void b(void)
{
  a(<all values to a()>);
}

#ifdef DEBUG
#  undef a
#endif

void a(<all param declarations to a()>)
{
  printf("'%s' called\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void a_debug(<all param declarations to a()>, const char * calledby)
{
  printf("'%s' calledby '%s'", __FUNCTION__, calledby);
  a(<all params to a()>);
}
#endif
```

If for example `<all param declarations to a()>` is `int i, double d, void * p` then `<all params to a()>` is `i, d, p`.

---

Or (less evil ;->> - but more code modding, as each call to a() needs to be touched):

```
void a((<all params of normal a()>    
#ifdef DEBUG
  , const char * calledby
#endif
  );

void a((<all params of normal a()>    
#ifdef DEBUG
  , const char * calledby
#endif
  )
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  printf("'%s' calledby '%s', __FUNCTION__, calledby);
#endif
  ...
}

...

void b(void)
{
    a(<all params of normal a()>
#ifdef DEBUG
      , __FUNC__
#endif
    );
}
```

---

`__FUNCTION__` is available on GCC (at least?), if using a different C99 compiler replace it with `__func__`.

Comment: :D it looks evil to me to but it IS a cool way of doing it IMO

Answer (score 5):

Refer: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

> A backtrace is a list of the function calls that are currently active
>   in a thread. The usual way to inspect a backtrace of a program is to
>   use an external debugger such as gdb. However, sometimes it is useful
>   to obtain a backtrace programmatically from within a program, e.g.,
>   for the purposes of logging or diagnostics.
>
> The header file execinfo.h declares three functions that obtain and
>   manipulate backtraces of the current thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only after knowing where you were for logging/debug purposes you can use a macro to avoid `__func__` giving the name of your logging/debug function but of the function calling it.

Being in a macro will not result in a change to `__func__` but will "feel" like using a function.

e.g.

```
#define LOG(s, data...) log("%s: "s, __function__, ## data)
```

Comment: Sry, but this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Since we don't know *why* they need to do this, it may.

Comment: can confirm Joe, it was actually exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 2):

If your platform is Windows, you may use this: [walking the callstack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack)

Answer (score 0):

You can tag each function that calls **a()** with an integer identifier which is passed to **a()** as a parameter and then use a **switch-case** construct in **a()** to tell which function has invoked  **a()**.A **printf()**  would tell which function invoked **a()** depending on the integer identifier value if you use that as an argument to a switch-case construct in **a()**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void a(int);
void b();
void c();
void d();

int main(void)
{

b();
c();
d();

}

void b()
{

int x=1;
a(x);

}

void c()
{

int x=2;
a(x);

}

void d()
{

int x=3;
a(x);

}

void a(int x)
{

switch(x)
{
case 1:
printf("b called me\n");
break;
 case 2:
printf("c called me\n");
break;
case 3:
printf("d called me\n");
}

}
```

Comment: It is a "workaround", not a solution. If you need to provide external API - your direct way will be useless.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I answered what the poster asked for.Not more,not less.It IS a solution.

Comment: It is not a solution, because you had changed function signature. Nevermind, it just my opinion ;)

Comment: Or, you can just pass `__FUNCTION__` into a(). No switch required, and it handles new functions, changed function names, etc. Of course, as Dmitry Sazonov says, adding that parameter _does_ change the function's signature.

Answer (score 0):

If the function in question is in a different c file, you can do

```
#define name_of_function(...) \
    printf("Function %s is parent\n", __FUNCTION__); \
    name_of_function(__VA_ARGS__);
```

And at the top of the c file it lives in

```
#ifdef name_of_function
#undef name_of_function
#endif
```

If they're in the same file, you can wrap the function definition in the second macro, then redefine the first macro at the end.
It's not terribly extensible because you can't generate new defines from other defines, but if you're trying to track down parents for a particular function it works without any nonsense.

https://godbolt.org/z/f2jKOm

Answer (score 0):

[Use another C-function as a wrapper for the original function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100246/21487921) which is to debug, means suppress the return data of the original function. Or you need to synchronize return types of the wrapper and the original function.

To avoid type-sync a C-macro should be used as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58244478/21487921):

```c
/* You need to debug the function foo().
 * So rename foo() to foo_debug() in source and header files.
 * Then define a macro named foo().
 *
 * Benefits:
 *   - you don't have to care about the return type
 *     of the original function;
 *   - C-macro is inline solution -- there are not
 *     extra calls in the backtrace.
 */

/* Function which is to debug after renaming. */
type_t foo_debug();

#define foo() \
    ({                                                       \
        fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] %s:%d %s() called by %s\n", \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, "foo", __FUNCTION__);    \
        foo_debug();                                         \
    })
```

Or one line C-macro:

```c
#define foo() (fprintf(stderr, "[DEBUG] %s:%d %s() called by %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, "foo", __FUNCTION__), foo_debug())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

#define FUNCTION_NAME(**FUNCTION**) printf("**FUNCTION**=%s \r\n",     #**FUNCTION**);

```
int a() {
  printf("A function call");
}

int b() {
  printf("B function call");
}

int main(){
FUNCTION_NAME(a);
FUNCTION_NAME(b);
return 0;
```

}