# How to track where destructor get called - C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, destructor

I'm wondering is there any predefined macro or something in C++ that could possible to trace back where the destructor is triggered?

It could be something like this:

```
    class myClass{
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    };
    myClass::~myClass(){
        printf("Object destroyed in %s.\n", __TRACEBACKMACRO__);
    }

    int main(){
    myClass tempClass;
    return 0;
    }
```

It should output something like this:

```
    Object destroyed in main().
```

It's better to output the scope and namespace information as well.

Additional information:
**FUNCTION** or **func** macro seems only work in functions not in structs and classes. [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). Any macros that work in struct and class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100090/how-can-we-know-the-caller-functions-name

Comment: Thank you, but how about scope and namespace information?

Comment: Is this for debugging? Then set a breakpoint on the destructor in the debugger. Are you on Linux?

Comment: Do not try to figure it out for each object just allocate them dynamically and dallocate them when ever you want.

Comment: You're basically asking how to find the stack trace. That's not a standard thing, but both GCC and MSVC appear to have (different) methods to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c http://stackoverflow.com/a/691742/321772

Comment: In my program the destructor get called 50+ times, breakpoint is too much works.... I'm working on Windows

Comment: The Itanium ABI for C++ specifies an unwinding API. You could probably use that to obtain a call trace (or use a ready-made library).

Comment: @Ashalynd Your link shows a nice debugging trick - having that in release code is plain wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the backtrace library though the avalability depends on the platform and compiler:

- with gcc compiler (Linux or MacOS X) to display the stacktrace in C++:

  include "execinfo.h" and use backtrace -> backtrace_symbols -> __cxa_demangle
- with Windows:

  include StackWalker.h and use StackWalker class

Have a look at this article http://oroboro.com/stack-trace-on-crash/ for ulterior details.

Alternatively you could use Boost.Call_stack: http://melintea.github.io/Boost-Call_stack/index.html