# Print name of caller function

Tags: c, linux, macros, c89

I found `__FUNCTION__` macro that will give the name of currently executing function, But is there any macro available to print the name of parent function (a function that invoked currently running function) ?

```
void print_error_message(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s : %s\n",__FUNCTION__,msg);
}

int main()
{
    print_error_message("failed to connect");
    return 0;
}
```

The above program will give output :

```
print_error_message : failed to connect
```

But what I actually required is

```
main : failed to connect
```

because `main()` invoked  `print_error_message()`

I don't want to pass one more argument to function `print_error_message()` like `print_error_message(__FUNCTION__, msg)`, what I am expecting is a similar macro or function to retrieve the name of the caller function.

Comment: you can try with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100090/how-can-we-know-the-caller-functions-name

Comment: Note that the standard name is `__func__`, which is a pre-defined identifier (see C11 [§6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2)).  The names `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` are GCC extensions.  See [What are the differences between `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)

Comment: Additionally, the GCC documentation on [function names as strings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) notes: _
These identifiers are variables, not preprocessor macros, and may not be used to initialize char arrays or be concatenated with string literals._

Comment: Why the `ansi` tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no standard way to get the name from the call-stack, and if debug information is stripped or otherwise unavailable there's possible no way at all to get the name.

As a simple workround, you could use macros:

```
#define print_error_message(msg) actual_print_error_message(__FUNCTION__, (msg))

void actual_print_error_message(const char *func, const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s : %s\n",func,msg);
}
```

Note that `__FUNCTION__` is not standard C, it's an extension. For standards-compliance use the C99 special predefined variable [`__func__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#func).

Answer (score 2):

You could let the caller pass its function name as a parameter. For example:

```
void print_error_message(const char *msg, const char *caller)
{
    printf("%s : %s\n",caller,msg);
}

int main()
{
    print_error_message("failed to connect", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not available and it is not possible.

Because value of a macro like `__FUNCTION__` is calculated in preprocessing phase and what you want to do is not possible in that phase.

Comment: But I hope there may any library functions that can do this job

Comment: Actually, the preprocessor doesn't know what a function is. so `__FUNCTION__` is not handled by the preprocessor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ? then what phase convert it into function name?

Comment: The compiler proper. It knows what functions are.

Answer (score 1):

> *I don't want to pass one more argument to function [...] I am expecting is a similar macro or function to retrieve the name of the caller function.*

This does not exist, at least not as part of the C standard.

On Linux GCC provides the capability to pull [backtrace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) info. Perhaps this helps you.